# IOS Swift 4 Hiding Keyboard while tapped around is interfering with button press

Tags: ios, keyboard, ibaction

I am using this extension to hide the keyboard when tapped around:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

When I hit the submit button when the keyboard is still active, the keyboard hides but there is no IBAction triggered.  The user has to tap the button once again to submit the details.

I have tried to use: isUserInteractionEnabled on the button and set it to true. It hasn't worked.